# Can I get a raw pointer from boost's weak_ptr?

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, weak-references

Is it possible to get a raw pointer from boost::weak_ptr? Boost's shared_ptr has get() method and "->" operator. Is there some rationale behind weak_ptr not having the same functionality?

Answer (score 16):

A `weak_ptr` holds a non-owning reference, so the object to which it refers may not exist anymore.  It would be inherently dangerous to use a raw pointer held by a `weak_ptr`.

The correct approach is to promote the `weak_ptr` to a `shared_ptr` using `weak_ptr::lock()` and get the pointer from that.

The [Boost `weak_ptr` documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/smart_ptr/weak_ptr.htm) explains why it would be unsafe to provide `get()` functionality as part of `weak_ptr`, and has examples of code that can cause problems.

Comment: For that matter, you can be left with a dangling pointer if you get a raw pointer for a `shared_ptr` that's destroyed afterwards too... in case of Multithread you can even be left with a dangling pointer in the run of the code `if (!weak.expired()) weak->run();` as the object pointed to could be destroyed between the test and the execution of the method (I suppose the method itself is properly synchronized)...

Comment: @Matthieu: of course you *can*, just as you can be left with a dangling pointer if you explicitly `delete` an object but keep a pointer to it. The point with having to promote a `weak_ptr` to `shared_ptr` is that it encourages you to correctly scope the use of the raw pointer, following the rules you normally use for `shared_ptr::get`. There would be no equivalent way to correctly scope the use of a raw pointer obtained directly from a `weak_ptr`.

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question and the accepted answer is good, so I hesitate to post another answer, but one thing that seems missing is a good idiomatic usage example:

```
boost::weak_ptr<T> weak_example;
...
if (boost::shared_ptr<T> example = weak_example.lock())
{
    // do something with example; it's safe to use example.get() to get the
    // raw pointer, *only if* it's only used within this scope, not cached.
}
else
{
    // do something sensible (often nothing) if the object's already destroyed
}
```

A key advantage of this idiom is that the strong pointer is scoped to the if-true block, which helps to prevent accidental use of a non-initialised reference, or keeping a strong reference around longer than it is actually required.

Answer (score 2):

You first need to derive the shared_ptr from the weak_ptr before getting hold of the raw pointer.

You can call [lock](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/smart_ptr/weak_ptr.htm#lock) to get the shared_ptr, or the shared_ptr constructor:

```
boost::weak_ptr<int> example;
...

int* raw = boost::shared_ptr<int>(example).get();
```

Comment: As written, this isn't safe - you could be left with a dangling pointer if the object is deleted when the temporary `shared_ptr` is destroyed. You should keep hold of the `shared_ptr` for as long as you're using the raw pointer.